# There exists x such that P(x) and there exists x such that not P(x) implies that there exists x,y such that x does not equal to y?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, natural-deduction

I'm trying to prove the following formula utilizing first order logic and natural deduction:
$$\exists xP(x)\land \exists x\lnot P(x) \supset \exists xy  (x\neq y) $$
So far I have tried assuming the left hand side and separating the following:
$$A1 \implies \exists xP(x)\land \exists x\lnot P(x) $$
$$A1 \implies \exists xP(x)$$
$$A1 \implies  \exists x\lnot P(x) $$

but I am stuck since I could not get rid of $\exists$. Am I missing something or is my way of approach wrong? Any help will be appreciated.

Edit: Available inference rules are all inference rules of the propositional logic, quantifier elimination & introduction, and substitution

Comment: I find the second part of your question very confusing. The premise is supposed to be $\exists xP(x)\land \exists x\neg P(x)$. What's that about $A_1$ implying parts of the premise?

Comment: The second part is just what I have been trying so far, it can be complete non-sense in this context and you may have an alternate approach

Comment: OK. Assuming the premise holds, you wish to prove that $\exists x\exists y\neg (x=y)$. From the premise and using the appropriate rules you can find $a,b$ such that $P(a)$ and $\neg P(b)$. Now start a new subproof with the premise $a=b$, find a contradiction, introduce the negation, etc.

Comment: That is the point I'm stuck at. There is no simple inference rule that eliminates $\exists$ with a free variable.

Comment: What point? I mentioned several. Please add the rules that you have available to the question. **Edit:** Also note that you only need to eliminate $\exists$ when the variable is bounded.

Comment: Edited the explanation to show the available rules

Comment: I hate making this mistake. I meant *bound*, not *bounded*. Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: I cannot proceed from the beginning until I find $P(a)$ and $\lnot P(b)$, after that it is possible for me to derive the right side with a contradiction

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50491/discussion-between-theycallmefm-and-git-gud).

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*

1) $∃xP(x) ∧ ∃x¬P(x)$ --- premise

2) $∃xP(x)$ --- $∧$-elim

3) $∃x¬P(x)$ --- $∧$-elim

4) $P(a)$ --- assumed [a] from 2) for $∃$-elim

5) $¬P(b)$ --- assumed [b] from 3) for $∃$-elim

6) $\forall x \forall y (x=y)$ --- assumed [c]

7) $a=b$ --- from 6)

8) $\bot$ --- from 4), 5), 7) and $=$-elim.

Now we can discharge [a] and [b] by $∃$-elim from 2) and 3) and apply $\to$-intro with 6) to conclude with :

> $¬\forall x \forall y (x=y)$.

Now, with *Double Negation*, we may derive : $∃x ∃y \ \lnot (x = y)$.